# scrollToOverflowEnable snap is not working with react-native-tab-view if one screen content is smaller than device height in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-scrollview

Trying to create collasable header + sticky bar with react-native-tab-view.

## Issue

- On changing tabs when scrollToOverflowEnable my animated tabBar snaps to the initial position sometime it doesn't work.
- On change of tab if content of one tab is not scrollable then it snaps to initial position but if I change to tab again and scroll then there is animation snap.

[snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/react-native-tab-view-with-sticky-header)

[image]

[image]